# Visual Studio 2022 ignores BaseIntermediateOutputPath property specified in project files

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, common-project-system

I have a solution containing a large number of projects.
To separate binaries from the sources, I changed `BaseOutputPath` to "..\bin" and `BaseIntermediateOutputPath` property in all projects to "..\obj".

It worked for the `BaseOutputPath` - all binaries are in the common directory.
For the intermediate path it didn't work at all. It broke the projects, because the `obj` directory is still created in the project folders, but now the files are not excluded from the project and appear as commitable for Git.

What am I doing wrong? Is it normal behavior? I don't want obj directories created in project directories. How can I achieve that behavior?

For now I just removed the property from projects. At least the `obj` folders are not shown as project folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MSBuild macros such as $(SolutionDir) or $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) and similar, if you do not want relative paths to start from your project file.

For example, you could set "BaseIntermediateOutputPath" to $(SolutionDir)\obj or better still to $(SolutionDir)\obj-$(Configuration). This way you will separate Debug and Release builds, which, if you don't, will get you into a lot of trouble.

Here is what I use in a particular "Directory.Build.props". Note the `<OutDir>` entry. This will change the output directory for all projects under this directory to the `stage64\lib` directory.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)..\stage64\lib\</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: And use "Directory.Build.props", if you don't already. Makes things a lot easier, especially with large projects.